# Glob pattern matching the first part of a file name

Tags: php, glob

In a directory I have filenames like 123X1.jpg, 23X1.jpg, 23X2.jpg, 4123X1.jpg.
I need the glob pattern to only get listed files starting with a required string.

For example:

```
'23X' -> 23X1.jpg, 23X2.jpg
'123X' -> 123X1.jpg
```

Last part part of the pattern is always an X. The first one is a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's trivial with `glob()`:

```
print_r(glob('/path/to/23X*.jpg'));
print_r(glob('/path/to/123X*.jpg'));
```

Comment: @dstonek: Yes, `glob` is powerful enough to even let you do `glob('/*/*/123X*.jpg')` but it'll be way slower of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `RegexIterator`

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$regex = new RegexIterator($fi, "/\dX[a-z\d]+/i");

foreach($regex as $file) {
    echo (string) $file, PHP_EOL;
}
```