# Find files in a directory with a partial string match

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory which contains the following files:

```
apple1.json.gz
apple2.json.gz
banana1.json.gz
melon1.json.gz
melon2.json.gz
```

I wish to find all of the `apple`, `banana` and `melon` file types.

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) I know that I can find by file type by:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.json.gz"):
    print(file)
```

However, in my case I can't match by file name or file type. Rather it is a partial file name match (all `apple`'s and so on)

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492775/glob-pattern-matching-the-first-part-of-a-file-name), this solution was proposed:

```
[in] for file in glob.glob('/path/apple*.json.gz'):
    print file
```

However, this returns zero

```
[out]
     0
```

Comment: Try `glob.glob('/path/apple*.json.gz')`. Mind the missing `s`.

Comment: Well noticed! This still returns nothing however

Comment: Then your absolute path `/path` does not contain the files. It does work for me.

Comment: I had a rogue `os.chdir` at the top of the file. Thank you

Comment: Yet you are specifying an absolute path...

Comment: Yes, the remnants of a previous method

Comment: `filename.startswith('apple')` is simpler than glob.

Comment: You can list the directory using listdir; and then do regex match on filenames with whatever pattern you may want. Finally, read only those files where you could find a match in its name

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Having the files in `/mydir` as follows

```
mydir
├── apple1.json.gz
├── apple2.json.gz
├── banana1.json.gz
├── melon1.json.gz
└── melon2.json.gz
```

you could either do

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir('/mydir')
for file in glob.glob('apple*.json.gz'):
    print file
```

or

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('/mydir/apple*.json.gz'):
    print file
```

Changing directories will not effect `glob.glob('/absolute/path')`.

Answer (score 3):

### Double List Comprehension Method

I was looking for a similar tool and developed a double list comprehension method that should work well for your case (I tested it for my case) ...

```
import os

def get_file_names_with_strings(str_list):
    full_list = os.listdir("path_to_your_dir")
    final_list = [nm for ps in str_list for nm in full_list if ps in nm]

    return final_list


print(get_file_names_with_strings(['apple', 'banana', 'melon']))
```